# Can you find who placed a call on the EDT from the AWTEvent object?

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, awt

There are some calls on the Event Dispatch Thread that I would like to know from where the call originated. I have a new class that extends and hooks into the `EventQueue`.

This allows me to override the `dispatchEvent()` routine and work with the `AWTEvent` object.

```
protected void dispatchEvent(AWTEvent event) 
{
    try 
    {
        preDispatchEvent();
        super.dispatchEvent(event);
    } 
    finally 
    {
        postDispatchEvent();
    }
}
```

Using the `AWTEvent.paramString()` routine, it prints the following which isn't very helpful:

```
    java.awt.event.InvocationEvent[INVOCATION_DEFAULT,runnable=sun.awt.GlobalCursorManager$NativeUpdater@1c926eac,notifier=null,catchExceptions=false,when=1563800245516] on sun.awt.windows.WToolkit@4020b9cf
```

Based on the `AWTEvent` object, is it possible to find which call placed the Event on the EDT?

Answer (score 0):

The AWTEvent method getSource() will tell you the object that caused the event to be dispatched. I'm not sure it is possible to tell exactly which call caused the event.